# Call button on headset defaults to skype. How to make it work with MS Teams?

Tags: skype, headset, microsoft-teams

I am using a headset which has 4 hardware buttons:

- **Volume +**
- **Volume -**
- **Microphone mute/unmute**
- **Call**

While my company worked with `Skype` this headset worked out of the box without the need to configure anuything and I kinda got used to it.

- **Volume buttons** would adjust system volume
- **Microphone mute/unmute** controls system microphone, however if `Skype` call is active, the status of the microphone would be
  replicated at application level in `Skype` (icon would change and other
  call participants would see that I am muted)
- **Call button** would bring up `Skype` main window if no call is active, answer call if there is an incoming call or hang up if there is a
  call in progress.

So far so good. Now we are moving to `MS Teams`. And the behavior has changed as follows:

- **Volume buttons** still adjust system volume, no problem here
- **Microphone mute/unmute** controls system microphone, but the behavior is not replicated in `Teams`. This means that when I press
  hardware mute button, microphone is muted at system level and my
  audio is no longer recorded or transmitted but in `Teams` people still
  see me as unmuted. This is a minor annoyance.
- **Call button** is completely ignored by MS `Teams` and defaults to `Skype`. No matter whatever the call status in `Teams` is, call button
  will just bring up main `Skype` window. I cannot hang up from the call
  in `Teams`, or answer `Teams` incoming call using headset.

I've done some searching but cannot find where this behavior is configured. Any ideas?

System:

- Windows 10 corporate edition
- `Skype` for Business for O365
  16.0.12430.20112 (32-bit)
- `Teams` Version 1.2.00.27559 (64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

I've a Plantronics Blackwire 3225 USB headset and it controls mute well in Skype for Business and Teams, but not in zoom.

In Plantronics Hub I can change target softphone to Zoom, but it still not works as expected.

I feel these features need to be enabled / improved by device manufacturer and you can't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Skype for Business seems to take exclusive control of the hardware buttons.

You can test this yourself very easily.  Close/quit Skype for Business.  Then start a Zoom meeting.  The hardware buttons work as expected.  Then launch Skype for Business, and the buttons won't work in Zoom anymore.

Once Skype for Business is disabled, any Zoom meetings have to be re-launched to get the buttons working in Zoom.

You can use the same test methodology for Teams. I'd wager a guess you'll see the same behavior.